# Проблема с датой в JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь сделать так чтобы, при отправке формы в БД записывалась дата отправки в формате "ДД.ММ.ГГГГ ЧЧ:ММ". Вот код:

```
const fullYear = Date().getDate() + "." + Date().getMonth() + "." + Date().getFullYear();
const time = Date().getHours() + ":" + Date().getMinutes();
const date = fullYear + " " + time;
```

Делал по туториалу https://learn.javascript.ru/datetime
Но при запуске nodejs получаю ошибку:
    Date(...).getDate is not a function
Подскажите пожалуйста как получить нужный мне формат даты и почему эта ошибка выходит, потому что многие туториалы говорят что именно так нужно дату получать.

Comment: сначала создайте обьект типа `Date`, так : `var atata = new Date();` а потом уже у переменной `atata` вызывайте упомянутый метод

Comment: А почему бы не использовать стандартное значение (что-то типа `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`) поля с датой в БД?

Comment: Спасибо, проблема решена

Comment: Извиняюсь, что не уточнил. Я использую CouchDB, и не знаю как добавить туда CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, если это вообще можно, но ответ Rostyslav Kuzmovych помог, проблема решена

Answer (score 4):

Спасибо за подсказку Rostyslav Kuzmovych.
Проблема решилась так:

```
const date = new Date();
const fullYear = date.getDate() + "." + date.getMonth() + "." + date.getFullYear();
const time = date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes();
const fullDate = fullYear + " " + time;
```